A way to resolve closed ALTs in VersionedTransaction
Solana StackExchange community. We have a code that parses VersionedTransactions using Anchor IDLs, to do that we need to know the complete list of addresses involved in a transaction (including ones from ALTs). Our current approach was the following:
const lookupTables = (
    await Promise.all(
        transaction.message.addressTableLookups.map((acc) => {
            if (acc) {
                return this.connection.getAddressLookupTable(
                    publicKey(acc.accountKey),
                        {
                            commitment: 'processed',
                        }
                );
            }
    })
))
    .map((table) => table?.value)
    .filter(Boolean) as AddressLookupTableAccount[]

const accounts = transaction.message
    .getAccountKeys({
        addressLookupTableAccounts: lookupTables,
    })
    .keySegments()
    .flat();

However, since we often need to parse historical data, some of those ALTs are already closed. Our initial idea was to fallback to .getParsedTransaction() (which has all the accounts resolved already), but that approach showed itself completely unefficient. Are there any better ways of handling this situation? Thank you in advance.

getParsedTransaction() is the approach to resolve this, since it's the only way to get access to the loaded addresses according to https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransaction. Otherwise you'll need to maintain a separate historical snapshot of address lookup tables
